# Asp.net accessing a unix box via ssh

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically i want to access my unix box via ssh and start executing some commands in there. How is this possible on asp.net web application. Any ideas tnx. Ill be using c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [Ssh.net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) before successfully to do just this.